# Are flat cables tangle-free?

Tags: physics, technology, consumer-products

Well, probably everybody knows and hates this. Detangling the headset cable when putting it out of your pocket.

[This headset product](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Ericsson-LiveSound-Premium-Headset-schwarz/dp/B005GDVBAE/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1327517627&sr=8-1) claims to prevent the cable from tangling up by the "flat cable technology". One of the product commenters on the site says, this "technology" doesn't work, cables are still tangling up, it's a constructional defect.

> Hear your music as it was meant to be heard. Discover LiveSound hi-fi headset.
>   Experience genuine Sony Ericsson sound. Deep, punchy bass. Balanced, clean and dynamic audio reproduction. LiveSound hi-fi headset. Premium design. **Flat tangle-free cables.** LiveKey app control. And remote on-cable music and call-handling. LiveSound. Engineered for music lovers.

What sounds intuitive to me is that by flat cables you reduce probably a bit/lot the friction between the cables. But is this a necessary/sufficient factor for cables getting tangled? Or more a matter of sufficient time and a tight enough pocket. It's unclear where this technology can work, if it works at all. Does friction play such a huge role?

Comment: depends if you simply push them in your pocket you'll have more chance of tangles than if you take the time to roll it up (stiffer cables will help reduce the tangles though)

Comment: I'm with @Ratchet on this - I don't get tangles. Maybe it's my OCD :-)

Comment: I used to get them tangled even if I took the time to roll them up :P

Comment: They are less likely, however I have used plenty of flat cables in home stereo wiring, and they defiantly get tangled. Usual they twist as they are, ie. they are not flat out of the spool.

Comment: This is a little like this question: Is tagliatelli less tangle prone than spaghetti? I'd say yes but not tangle-proof. :-)

Comment: Often when my cables get tangled, they aren't knotted like a shoelace, but rather, the middle is wrapped around another part of the middle, making them appear tied.  It's ofen possible to completely (or mostly) untangle them, without ever moving the ends back through a loop in the cable.  Obviously just about any cable can be tied,  But perhaps these headphones are good a preventing certain types of tangles.

Comment: They do sometimes tangle but very rarely, and its not like the original wires where it takes like an hour to untangle them

Comment: I will say this: I've never had a SATA cable tangle. Regarding headphones, I realized a while ago that if, at the end of wrapping them, wrap them around the wrap (loop), they won't tangle (same way guitar strings are packaged, and they don't tangle). Regarding the original question: tangle _resistant_? Sure. Tangle _proof_? No.

Comment: Sounds to me that the material, especially stiffness, is much more important than the shape.